# Temporaily slow down "scroll wheel" speed on Magic Mouse?

Tags: safari, macos, mouse, google-maps

I have the "scroll wheel" speed on my Magic Mouse set to highest possible. Is there a way to slow it down just temporarily in Safari? You can achieve other similar "slow downs" in the system by pressing certains keys (shift and click the zoom button for a window to slow down the animation, alt-shift and volume keys to adjust the volumes with higher resolution etc) but nothing I have tried work in Safari.

Specifically, there is a Google Map web application I want a slower zoom for. Currently when I use the scroll wheel I go from recognizing cars to country level by just breathing on the mouse.